# Русские буквы не отображаются при парсинге XML

Tags: java, android, xml

Здравствуйте! 
Пытаюсь парсить сайт : http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
Parserhandler handler = new Parserhandler();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
InputSource is = new InputSource("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
is.setEncoding("iso-8859-1");
parser.parse(is, handler);
```

Вообще пробовал различные варианты кодировки **utf-8**, **Cp1251** и т.д

но в ответ получаю символы типа:

> Þæíîàôðèêàíñêèõ ðýíäîâ

или получаю ошибку

> unknown encoding/

помогите пожалуйста